# Translating "John is an adult man" into First Order Logic and Prover9 input

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, theorem-provers

I am working on translating a really simple English statement into First Order Logic, which is-
"John is an adult man"
My first order logic axioms are the following-

```
Man(x) -> Person(x).
Adult(x) <-> (Person(x) & Age(x)>=18).
Woman(x) -> Person(x).
Child(x) <-> (Person(x) & Age(x)<18).
Man(John).
Man(x) -> -Woman(x).
Age(John) = 30.
```

I am trying to prove whether John is an adult by the axiom-

```
Adult(John)
```

However Prover9 displays Exhausted and cannot search for a proof. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Using axiom Man(John) you derive that Person(John) (1st axiom). Using Age(John)=30 you have Adult(John) by 2nd axiom.

Comment: Yes you are right. However Prover9 fails to prove this and exhausts the search space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to math.SE!

What you're trying to prove is not true. You can ask `mace4` to generate a counter-model for you (it will find one of size 31 almost immediately. You will see that in the counter-model, `<` and `>=` are both defined as the empty relation.

How is this possible? In the language of Prover9, the symbols `<` and `>=` do not refer to the usual order relations $<, \geq$ of the natural numbers: instead, they are just arbitrary relational symbols that are governed by the axioms (and only the axioms) that you give to Prover9.

This is exactly what users of Prover9 want to happen: they work with general structures that come equipped with various orderings (e.g. ones defining an Alexandroff topology on some weak algebraic structure) that have nothing to do with the ordering of the natural numbers.

You should not try to use Prover9 to solve problems that involve natural numbers and the usual order relations $<,\leq$ in this fashion. It is technically possible to use Prover9 to solve problems involving arithmetic, but you'll be fighting an uphill battle.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for the amazingly detailed answer. So you are saying that my First Order Logic statements are correct but cannot be easily proved using Prover9? And is there any other logic prover I can use to build such a Knowledge Base and derive meaningful  proofs from?

Comment: And Is there any other way I can rewrite my axioms so that they can work in Prover9?

Comment: @SushantDahiya You can add e.g. the axioms  `-(x < y) -> x >= y.` and `-(30 < 18).` to make things work, but this is a temporary fix. You'd have to add larger and larger sets of axioms to cover a larger range of facts, and once your axioms become too complicated, or once you get too many of them, Prover9 won't be able to conclude anything anymore.

Comment: So, as I wrote in the answer, Prover9 is really not meant to be used in this fashion. Is there any other logic prover you could use to do what you'd like? Probably. Some theories available in the Z3 solver might be up to this task. You could try asking that as a separate question (not sure what would be the best place for it, perhaps Stack Overflow?).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!